# segmentatio fault en programiz C

Tags: c

tengo un problema algo estresante, en programiz C hice un algoritmo que simulé un juego de dados con solamente usar un dado, el código esta así tal cual escrito

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int tirarDado() {
  int dado = 1 + rand() % 6;
  return dado;
}

int main() {
  //Informar cant de jugadores y sus nombres
  int cant_jugadores;
  int nombres[cant_jugadores];
  printf("Ingrese el numero de jugadores: ");
  scanf("%d", &cant_jugadores);

  for(int i = 0; i < cant_jugadores; i++){
    printf("Ingrese el nombre %dº jugador: ", i+1);
    scanf("%s", nombres[i]);
  }

  //Simular tiradas de dados
  int puntajes[cant_jugadores], totalPuntajes = 0;
  int nombreJugador, puntaje;
  for(int i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
    puntaje = tirarDado();
    puntajes[i-1] = puntaje;
    totalPuntajes += puntaje;
  }

  //Buscar y mostrar el jugador que ganó
  nombreJugador = 0;
  int mayorPuntaje = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < cant_jugadores; i++){
    if(puntajes[i] > mayorPuntaje) {
      nombreJugador = i;
      mayorPuntaje = puntajes[i];
    }
  }
  printf("El jugador que ganó es: %s con un puntaje de %d", nombres[nombreJugador], mayorPuntaje);
  
    return 0;
}
```

yo lo que hago es imprimir este código pongo como ejemplo, cantidad de jugadores 2,y pongo el nombre del jugador 1, pero cuando le doy enter, me sale segmentation fault en el output, que puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Estás cometiendo cuatro errores graves en tu código.

---

**Primero** estás definiendo una formación<sup>1</sup> cuyo tamaño desconoces

```
int cant_jugadores;
int nombres[cant_jugadores];
```

Ahí vemos que a `cant_jugadores` no se le da valor alguno y acto seguido se usa para que la formación `nombres` decida su tamaño. Usar variables que no han sido inicializadas es [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido).

**El siguiente** error es precisamente usar una variable (`cant_jugadores`) para definir el tamaño de una formación, las formaciones necesitan conocer su tamaño en tiempo de compilación, en caso contrario estás definiendo una [VLA](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+vla) cuyo soporte por los compiladores es limitado.

**El tercer** error es que los datos no se actualizan retroactivamente  ¡recuerda que el código se ejecuta de arriba a abajo!: al leer `cant_jugadores` la formación `nombres` no va a cambiar de tamaño retroactivamente automágicamente, se quedará con el tamaño inicial (que es desconocido).

**Finalmente** estás leyendo los nombres de los jugadores como texto, pero la formación en que pretendes guardarlos es de enteros (`int`), esto no va a funcionar nunca.

```
for(int i = 0; i < cant_jugadores; i++){
  printf("Ingrese el nombre %dº jugador: ", i+1);
  scanf("%s", nombres[i]); // ¿%s? ¡pero nombres[i] es int!
}
```

En resumen, antes de acabar `main` tu código ha tenido al menos cuatro oportunidades de fallar.

---

1<sub>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.</sub>